# default /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf example

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, phpmyadmin

I am looking for a full example of a /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf config.
While I was editing the file, accidentally saved the file...

The only code that is left..

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin/>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 127.0.0.1
    allow from 192.168.1.0/15
</Directory>

<RequireAny>
    Require all granted
</RequireAny>

Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Currently running CentOS 7 in VMware Workstation.

Comment: You can reinstall the package. To find the package associated with the file use `rpm -qf /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf` then followed by `yum reinstall <packagename>-<version>` where packagename and version is returned by previous command. The config file will not be overwritten but the new one will be saved as `/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf.rpmnew`.

Comment: Or you can download the rpm package and extract the files into /tmp. `cd /tmp; rpm2cpio <packagename>-<version>.rpm | cpio -idmuv`. The file will be located in `/tmp/etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf`.

Comment: @alvits you should repost your comments as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I fixed the configuration!