# phpmyadmin.conf default file

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

First of all, I'm pretty new to this all...

I am using Amazon web services and I have installed LAMP on Amazon linux using  [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html).

When installing phpmyadmin, I was trying to grant access to all IP addresses (i know, not a good idea), so I tried adding Require all granted under # Apache 2.4 in phpmyadmin.conf file, I was using Mac's terminal, and I messed up the file while trying to learn how to add it, so now that I found how to add it, it is not working anymore... this the error I get:

```
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]  
Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf:  
Invalid command '# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Is there anyway that I can just replace the phpMyAdmin.conf file to default and start editing it over?
or do I have to unistall and re install phpmyadmin all over again?

Thanks

Comment: please format your question. You have tips on right side when create questions

Comment: Done! thanks so much, I was wondering why it's showing up so weird...

Comment: There are some reasonable suggestions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290736/default-etc-httpd-conf-d-phpmyadmin-conf-example

Comment: Thanks, I did see that question, but to be honest, I couldn't follow the answer... maybe it's because I'm a noob but is it possible you for you to elaborate a little more? thanks so much!!